# How to set the default edit distance in fuzzy search from 2 to 1?

Tags: solr, lucene, edismax

I am using edismax parser. I have many fields in my schema and fullText is one of them.I am using this query:

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/simple/select?q=design~+chair~&wt=json&defType=edismax&qf=fullText
```

(Check the ~ symbol after query words)

Now when i use debugQuery i find out that this internally querying for this:

```
"parsedquery_toString": "+((fullText:design~2) (fullText:chair~2))"
```

Is there any way i can change the default edit distance from 2 to 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a parameter to the fuzzy search... so `design~1` for instance will give you an edit distance of 1

Comment: I know that.Actually i am using edismax parser which also supports phrase slop.When it creates a phrase from query(q) it removes the ~(tidle) character.
So for q=design~+chair~ , it creates a phrase "design chair" so i am able to use phrase slop here.But when i use q=design~1+chair~1 , it creates the phrase as "design 1 chair 1" which is meaning less for me.I know there is some plugin to handle this.But i am looking for a simple solution.
Also it would be good for me to change the edit distance value to 1 in some central place because i am using 1 only.